# Download embedded links in a html page using wget

Tags: linux, unix, wget

I am trying to download the package from https://github.com/justintime/nagios-plugins/downloads using wget, but what I am getting is the html file of the link I mentioned not the package. I tried this command:

```
wget -r -l 1 https://github.com/justintime/nagios-plugins/downloads
```

Is there any way to download the package from the above link?

Comment: wget can actually do what you are asking for in the title, but it's *not* what you want to do in this case, because it would download quite a lot of extra stuff you don't need like all images and some other html files and both archives, though they are equivalent etc.

Comment: @JanHudec Ok, how do you do that?  I came here trying to do what the title is actually asking.

Comment: @Michael: This question is answered and is answered correctly. If you want to do something else (which is likely; this question is rather specific), _and can't find answer by simply reading the manual_, ask another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wget` is giving you what you asked for. You *dint* specify the *package* link. You are specifying the *page* link. Right click on the `Download` button of the required package on the page and select `Copy Link Address` and specify *that* address to `wget`

This works

```
wget -r -l 1 https://github.com/justintime/nagios-plugins/zipball/master
```

Comment: @ShankhoneerChakrovarty Actually your recursive option should also have worked as the package download link is there in the main downloads page.(I even tried with higher depths to no avail) I am not sure why `wget` itself dint search for those links and download, as `-r` is specified.